# Same-origin request causes “Access-Control-Allow-Origin doesn’t match” error, though origin of course matches. Note: has CSP policy w/ "sandbox"

Tags: javascript, firefox, cors, sandbox, content-security-policy

When the *exact* *same* URL is being used in both by CORS and its web pages' URL, I still get the same error messages in my Firefox development console.

Browser console messages were:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: \
  The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource \
  at https://egbert.net/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0. \
  (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not \
  match ‘https://egbert.net’).
```

## Header Settings, lighttpd Server

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://egbert.net
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range
Content-Security-Policy: \
    default-src 'none'; \
    base-uri 'none'; \
    script-src 'strict-dynamic'; \
    object-src 'none'; \
    style-src 'self'; \
    img-src https://egbert.net/favicon.ico https://egbert.net/images/ https://egbert.net/blog/articles/*/images/*.png data:; \
    media-src https://egbert.net/media/ data:; \
    frame-src https://egbert.net/frames/; \
    frame-ancestors 'self'; \
    worker-src 'self'; \
    child-src https://egbert.net/frames/; \
    font-src https://egbert.net/fonts/; \
    connect-src 'self' https://egbert.net/; \
    form-action 'none'; \
    require-trusted-types-for; \
    trusted-types template; \
    sandbox; \
    report-uri https://ssoseo1.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/enforce; \
    report-to endpoint-1; \
    upgrade-insecure-requests; \
    block-all-mixed-content;
Feature-Policy: accelerometer 'none'; camera 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; geolocation 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; microphone 'none'; midi 'none'; notifications 'none'; payment 'none'; push 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; speaker 'none'; usb 'none'; vibrate 'none';
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
```

HTML settings

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://egbert.net/css/m-dark.compiled.css">
```

### CSS path

```css
 */@font-face {
 font-family:'FontAwesome';
 src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
 src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'),
 url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'),
 url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'),
 url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'),
 url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
 font-weight:normal;
 font-style:normal
}
```

I've ensured that all font files are able to be downloaded by the same browser in separate tabs.

And what's weirder is that the error message implies "remote resource".   They're the exact same URL.

No plugins were loaded, this is safe mode Firefox v73.0.1.

## Update 1

It didn't change anything when I replaced the relative path ('../fonts') in the `/@font-face` of CSS with an absolute directory path.

## Update 2

It didn't change anything when I added the scheme and domain (https://egbert.net/) to the `/@font-face` of CSS in front of the absolute directory path for a full-blown URL path.

This is not the same issue as:

- [Why doesn’t Postman get a “No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101)
- [Font from origin has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577981/)
- [Firefox 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked' despite headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371734/firefox-cross-origin-request-blocked-despite-headers)
- [How to get a cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) post request working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/)
- [Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454519/)
- [Same origin Policy and CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681292/)
- [Socket.IO: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754146/)
- [google maps - Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24925322)
- [Cross-Origin Request Blocked Microsoft Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503686/)

Comment: Try changing your Content-Security-Policy response header to have `sandbox allow-same-origin` rather than just `sandbox` — or else, completely drop the `sandbox` directive from your CSP policy. Is there a particular reason why you added it? What exactly are you using it to try to prevent? The reason you need to add `allow-same-origin` is, without that added, if you specify `sandbox`, then browsers are required to set the origin of your document to `null`. And I think that’s what’s causing your font request to fail: The browser won’t blocks the request because the document origin is null.

Comment: Details on when browsers set an origin to null are at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42242802/441757. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#attr-iframe-sandbox, explains the specific condition in his case: when `sandbox` is set, *“the content is treated as being from a unique origin; forms, scripts, and various potentially annoying APIs are disabled, links are prevented from targeting other browsing contexts, and plugins are secured. The `allow-same-origin` keyword causes the content to be treated as being from its real origin instead of forcing it into a unique origin”*

Comment: @sideshowbarker, THIS IS IT!!!!   Problem SOLVED!  replacing 'sandbox' with 'sandbox allow-same-origin' in the CSP portion of HTTP header did THAT trick.  Oh my, oh my, what a relief.   10 days of agony solved in ... seconds.  As to why I am doing this security thing, it is a proof of concept that one can go 'uber' and get it to work, of which you did.  Thank you so very much!

Comment: Updated OP to show CSP portion of HTTP-RESPONSE header.  Please post answer for my wonderful acceptance, @sideshowbarker

Comment: A bug report over at Mozilla for an enhancement request to FIX the wording of the error message so that others may not fall into this trap.  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1644503

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `sandbox` with `sandbox allow-same-origin` in the CSP policy will fix the problem.

**Explanation:**

The CORS problem the question describes is ultimately caused by the  browser having set the origin value to `null`. So even though the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is set to the origin value that’d normally be expected — matching the URL shown in the browser address bar — it actually doesn’t match, due to the fact the browser has set the origin to `null`.

So you end up in what looks like a paradox: the document seeming to not match its own origin.

The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42242802/441757 outlines all cases where browsers set an origin to `null`. The specific cause of the case in the question arises from requirements at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/#attr-iframe-sandbox which say, if `sandbox` is set:

> content is treated as being from a unique origin, forms, scripts, and various potentially annoying APIs are disabled, links are prevented from targeting other browsing contexts, and plugins are secured. The `allow-same-origin` keyword causes the content to be treated as being from its real origin instead of forcing it into a unique origin.

So the bottom line is: Whenever you specify `sandbox`, in most cases you want to be specifying it with the `allow-same-origin` keyword included — in order to prevent surprising and hard-to-troubleshoot problems/side-effects such as the CORS problem described in the question.

Comment: There seems to be an update...  `sandbox` attribute  is for iframe.  "Only" for iframe?  What about the main/parent DOM context/page?

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#attr-iframe-sandbox

Comment: Basically, this HTTP specification is a "TRI-STATE" logic mechanism.  We start at 'unknown', then flip to either 'allowed' or 'disallowed'.   And 'unknown' is defaulted to 'not-allowed'?  Something like that?

Comment: Specifying `sandbox` is like specifying “disallow everything” or “deny all”. So if you have `sandbox` specified but you want to allow specific things, you need to use the `allow-*` to add back the specific things you want to allow.

Comment: Just to be clear, specifying `sandbox` alone without any suboptions will block everything.  Whereas, not specifying anything `sandbox` defaults to everything allowable.